# Postgres: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bigint

Tags: postgresql

My query is something like this. I try to get a status for a list of ids.

```
select order_number, order_status_name
from data.order_fact s
join data.order_status_dim l
on s.order_status_key = l.order_status_key
where 
order_number in (1512011196169,1512011760019,1512011898493,1512011972111)
```

I get an error though that says:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = bigint
LINE 6: order_number in (1512011196169,1512011760019,1512011898493,1...
                     ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Do you have any clue on how I should reform the ids to get it work?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: One more scenario for This question and the accepted answer - when one of your parameters is an Enum and during replacement its order value is used , not its name.So you would have this kind of 'comparing varchar to smallint' error

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your `order_number` is  a varchar, you can't compare that to a number (`123` is a number in SQL, `'123'` is a string constant)

You need to use string literals:

```
order_number in ('1512011196169','1512011760019','1512011898493','1512011972111')
```

More details in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Answer (score 3):

If you can't change the type of numbers within `in`, you could use `cast`:

```
select * from numbers_as_string
where cast(my_numbers_as_string as int) in (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happen too when you are using native query in sprinboot and you are passing a parameter as string but that field is a (integer or long) in your model/entity, also when you are comparing a string with a integer due that param is used like string without casting.
so you should cast it as integer in the native query like this

> x\:\:integer

for example:

```
       @Query(value=" 
        ......
    .....
         inner join tablex t on t.x\\:\\:integer = pv.id \n"+
....
....
        ")
         List<Object> getMyQuery(@Param("x") String x)
```