# Postgres, query error: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bigint?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to run this query:

```
select *
from my_table
where column_one=${myValue}
```

I get the following error in Datagrip:

```
[42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bigint Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Now, I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740652/postgres-error-operator-does-not-exist-character-varying-bigint), and I can fix the error by putting a string like this:

```
select *
from my_table
where column_one='123'
```

What I need is a way to pass in the '123' as a parameter. I usually do this `${myValue}` and it works, but I am not sure how to keep my variable there as an input so I can run dynamic queries in code and let Postgres understand I want to pass in a string and not a number.

Any suggestions?

Here's a screenshot of how I am putting the parameter value in DataGrip...:
[image]

Ok, so, I just tried to put quotes in the data grip parameters input field for myValue @thirumal's answer things work. I didn't know I have to quote the value for it to work.
This is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: but how are you binding the ``myValue`` parameter? can you show us how you execute the query?

Comment: ${myValue}::varchar

Comment: Which programming language and database interface are you using? As Marc already mentioned: the code that runs that statement and passes the parameter is important

Comment: I am using Datagrip from JetBrains. I literally pasted in the query as shown and then set the value in the parameters pop up. ( have attached a screenshot of that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type cast `${myValue}` using SQL Standard,

```
cast(${myValue} AS varchar)
```

or using Postgres Syntax:

```
${myValue}::varchar
```

Comment: I have tried that, but, if the string I pass in to myValue has a "+" in it the query runs but it will not find the row. if column_one has value "+123", and then I pass in "+123", the query won't match the row, so, empty result. If I modify column_one to be "123" and then run the query with myValue "123" then things work. Why is the "+" breaking the query? (I tried both, same problem with both)